# Android catch MediaPlayer errors

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

I want to catch below exception in android about mediaplayer.

```
 11-28 11:44:17.801  21290-21290/com.xxx.xxx E/MediaPlayer﹕ internal/external state mismatch corrected
```

or

```
 E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
 E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
```

But my Activity  had to implement

```
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener
```

```
 @Override
 public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
     Log.i(TAG, "On Error what:" + what + "/"+extra);
          return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
     Log.i(TAG, "On Error what:" + what +"/"+extra);
  }
```

and set mediaplayer exception

```
  try {
   mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                mMediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tutor);
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "error:" + e.getMessage());

    }
```

But they are not catching the error.

Does any one know how to catch these error codes or message and in what method?

thank you very much

Comment: If it's not throwing an exception then you can't catch it. What happens with the `onError` method; does it get called appropriately?

Comment: If show these error , that are not show in onError method. But the media was stop.

Comment: The media player play on the start, but play some time, it will show these error, so I want to catch these error and show some alert to user.

Comment: mp.setdatasore(<datasouurce>),mp.preparasync() and then in onprepare() put mp.start() and please implement onpreparedlistener interface. I hope you have done this

Comment: My code orginal is put the mediaplayer.start() in the onprepare() method. I had implement  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.

Comment: I'm using onError but the "what" and "extra" code is far more than 7 which provided in constants.